# ld: library not found for -lPods-Unity-iPhone clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

ld: library not found for -lPods-Unity-iPhone
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

please help

Answer (score 0):

Deleted lPods-Unity-iPhone.a in main project and now works.